# warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]

Tags: c++, c, arrays, mud

I'm having a problem with the following piece of code throwing warnings and hoping you could help me:

```
   fprintf (fp, "%dd%d+%d ", pMobIndex->mana[DICE_NUMBER],
```

`DICE_NUMBER` is defined in my header file as 0.

Obviously, 0 is not exceeding the size of the array.

The array is defined as.

```
   int               mana[2];
```

I have absolutely no idea why it would be doing this, as 0 is clearly within the bounds of the array.  Half of my engines code is throwing these array bound errors now, I've got about 30 of them, and *NONE* of them make sense to me.

Here is the output from make:

```
  gcc -O3 -s -Wall -c -o obj/olc_save.o olc_save.c
olc_save.c: In function 'save_mobile':
olc_save.c:234:13: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
     fprintf (fp, "%dd%d+%d ", pMobIndex->mana[DICE_NUMBER],
         ^
```

it also happens:

```
db1.c: In function 'create_mobile':
db1.c:2056:30: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
             + pMobIndex->mana[DICE_BONUS];
```

and

```
olc_act.c: In function 'medit_manadice':
olc_act.c:6500:15: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
     pMob->mana[DICE_BONUS] = atoi (bonus);
```

The definition in my header file:

```
/* dice */
#define DICE_NUMBER  0
#define DICE_TYPE    1
#define DICE_BONUS   2
```

I'm aware `DICE_BONUS` will be (realizing it only now) but I for the life of me cannot figure out why `DICE_NUMBER` is.

D'oh.  The problem is that the third integer output there on the `fprintf` is `DICE_BONUS` but its on another line, I thought the compiler was warning me about `DICE_NUMBER`, it was warning me about BONUS.

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) please, or it didn't happen.

Comment: Are you sure that Warning is because of code shown???

Comment: Update to your own question plz, not as a comment.

Comment: DICE_BONUS will obviously be out of bounds in your case

Answer (score 3):

`mana[2]` is an integer array for two elements and `DICE_BONUS` is defined as 2 so `mana[2]` means you are trying to access third element.

REMEMBER array starts from `0` subscript. So all warnings related to `DICE_BONUS` is valid. You need to redefine your array for three elements.

Now about `DICE_NUMBER` that is not causing warning. Perhaps you have some additional argument on that line which includes `DICE_BONUS` there too.

Comment: In fact, considering that his format string takes three integers meant to display stuff like `4d6 + 1` it's seems likely that the rest of the `printf` function call includes `pMobIndex->mana[DICE_BONUS]` further on.